# Is it possible to have AFOAuth2Client work with AFNetworking 2?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2, afoauth2client

I keep getting an error that `AFOAuthClient` requires `AFNetworking 1.3` but AFNetworking was updated to 2.0 a few months ago. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

AFOAuth2Client doesn't officially support 2.0 yet, there were a few changes that needed to be made to the code base.

People have made the changes but they just haven't been rolled into the main branch yet.

I'd read through this for the changes [AFOAuth2Client GitHub](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Client/pull/50)